# How to use sed to substitute LF with space, but not CRLF?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a csv file, that has a mix of **CRLF** and **LF**. At some points there is a **LF**, where in fact the content belongs to the line before.

Example:

```
smith;pete;he is very nice;1990CRLF
brown;mark;he is very nice;2010CRLF
taylor;sam;he isLF
very nice;2009CRLF
```

In my script, I want to remove all standalone instances of **LF**.
I tried using sed:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' $my_file
```

The problem with this solution is that the **LF**s belonging to the **CRLF**s, also get substituted with a space character.

Comment: Can you once try with Unicode for `LF`?

Comment: With GNU sed, you may use [`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/<<<CRLF>>>/g;s/\n/ /g;s/<<<CRLF>>>/\r\n/g;' my_file`](https://ideone.com/uRKbx3), but probably only if the file is not too big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `perl` which doesn't remove record separator by default - and thus allowing easy manipulation

```
$ cat -A ip.txt
smith;pete;he is very nice;1990^M$
brown;mark;he is very nice;2010^M$
taylor;sam;he is$
very nice;2009^M$

$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /' ip.txt
smith;pete;he is very nice;1990
brown;mark;he is very nice;2010
taylor;sam;he is very nice;2009

$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /' ip.txt | cat -A
smith;pete;he is very nice;1990^M$
brown;mark;he is very nice;2010^M$
taylor;sam;he is very nice;2009^M$
```

`(?<!\r)\n` uses negative look-behind to ensure that we replace `\n` only when it is not preceded by `\r`

Modifying OP's attempt:

```
$ sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\([^\r]\)\n/\1 /g' ip.txt
smith;pete;he is very nice;1990
brown;mark;he is very nice;2010
taylor;sam;he is very nice;2009
```

`\([^\r]\)` to ensure character preceding `\n` is not `\r`

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"}/\n/{sub(/\n/,"")}1' file
smith;pete;he is very nice;1990
brown;mark;he is very nice;2010
taylor;sam;he isvery nice;2009
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS=ORS="\r\n" }  # set the record separators to CRLF
/\n/ {                   # if there is stray LF in the record
    sub(/\n/,"")         # remove it (maybe " " to replace it with a space)
}1' file                 # output it
```

Tested succesfully on gawk, mawk and Busybox awk. Fails with BSD awk, use for example:

```
awk '!/\r$/{printf "%s",$0;next}1' file
```